# replacing timestamp with date using sed

Tags: shell, date, sed, gnu

When using SED to replace timestamps with human readable dates the timestamp is always replaced with the epoch date plus the value placed after"\"

I have this working with Perl example but prefer to use sed. I have tried varying escape sequences and quoting "'` etc.

```
sed -re "s/([0-9]{10})/$(date -d @\1)/g" mac.txt
```

input (one string):

```
834|task|3||1561834555|Ods|12015|info|Task HMI starting 837|task|3||1561834702|Nailsd|5041|info|Configured with engine 6000.8403 (/opt/NAI/LinuxShield/engine/lib/liblnxfv.so), dats 9297.0000 (/opt/NAI/LinuxShield/engine/dat), 197 extensions, 0 extra drivers
```

Expect date conversion but results are:

```
834|task|3||Wed Dec 31 19:00:01 EST 1969|Ods|12015|info|Task HMI starting 837|task|3||Wed Dec 31 19:00:01 EST 1969|Nailsd|5041|info|Configured with engine 6000.8403 (/opt/NAI/LinuxShield/engine/lib/liblnxfv.so), dats 9297.0000 (/opt/NAI/LinuxShield/engine/dat), 197 extensions, 0 extra drivers 838|task.
```

basically:
this is what is being called:

```
$(date -d @\1) instead of $(date -d @\1561834555)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed never sees the `$(date -d @\1)` -- the shell has executed that command substitution **before** sed launches.

You could something like this:

```
sed -Ee 's/([0-9]{10})/$(date -d @\1)/g' -e 's/^/echo "/' -e 's/$/"/' mac.txt | sh
```

(note the single quotes, preventing the shell from doing any expansions)

*However*, it's much more sensible to use a language that has date facilities built-in. GNU awk:

```
gawk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i ~ /^[0-9]{10}$/)
            $i = strftime("%c", $i)
    print
}' mac.txt
```

Perl will probably be installed:

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -pe 's{\b(\d{10})\b}{ strftime("%c", localtime $1) }ge' mac.txt
# or, this is more precise as it only substitutes *fields* that consist of a timestamp
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -F'\|' -lape '$_ = join "|", map { s/^(\d{10})$/ strftime("%c", localtime $1) /ge; $_ } @F' mac.txt
```

Comment: the sed command worked perfectly, I can't test gawk at the moment as I don't have it installed. Would you clarify what -e 's/^/echo "/' -e 's/$/"/' does? I am only learning sed now for a current project. thanks so much

Comment: wait i think i see... places echo " at the begining of the line and " at the end resulting in echo"$date( -d @1155....)". is that correct?

Comment: Pretty much. Run it without `|sh` and you'll see what it does. I'm constructing *shell commands* so the `date` command substitutions can be evaluated in a shell.

Comment: @vintnes, I see your answer but I can't comment on it. I would argue that perl is more portable than gawk.

Comment: Thanks Glenn you’ve been most helpful